# onPause() and onStop() not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

```
public class PhrasesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

        final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

#some Word elements added
        WordAdapter wordAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words, R.color.category_phrases);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.numberlist);
        listView.setAdapter(wordAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(PhrasesActivity.this, "Demo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Word word = words.get(i);
                releaseMediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PhrasesActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceID());
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
            }
        });
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("PhrasesActivity", "onPause: Paused");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("PhrasesActivity", "onPause: Stopped");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

    private void releaseMediaPlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer!= null){
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer= null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code isn't working in child-activity in my app.
I have tried checking logs with `Log.v()` but, nothing is happening at all. No log is created.
**EDIT**
-I tried using onPause() method only. That also didn't helped me solve the problem.

Comment: what is a *sub-activity*? Also you didn't `@Override` these methods

Comment: I meant child activity, sorry about that. I used command (control + o in Android studio on Windows PC). How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the entire class so we can see how / what is happening.

Comment: print your hole "child"-activity and also the "parent"-activity if there is one. Note: there is no such term in android as child activity. Maybe you mean fragment?

Comment: I don't think that there is such a thing as `child activity` in Android as well. How do you use it? Or post a full code

Comment: you must write `#SomeCode` before calling the `super class` in pause, destroy, stop, etc

Comment: Do you use it inside of TabActivity? If so, better use fragment and TabLayout

Comment: where do you use it? how do you start this activity?

Comment: Vlad, this is my second activity in the app, on which I am directing through my MainActivity. This is an activity from Udacity course in which miwok app is created as a project. You can find this same onPause() method in lesson 4, 28th video naming "sample app with life cycle callback".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error in the code is in the sequence of using required instruction statements before calling super.onStop()/super.onPause();

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // super.onPause();
    Log.v("PhrasesActivity", "onPause: Paused");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // super.onStop();
    Log.v("PhrasesActivity", "onPause: Stopped");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Generally, in java we first call super(); in overridden method and then proceed for further code writing.
I didn't get why it is not followed here, but changing code as above helped me solve the problem.

Thanks to Mohammed Atif for help!

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

In original Udacity tutorial they used only `onStop` method.

But, only `onStop` or only `onPause` did not work for me.

By adding both of them (as written above), it works fine for me (Android 10). (And also, it is not mandatory to call `super.____()` after calling `releaseMediaPlayer()`.)

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the override tag and make sure you are extending Activity

Example

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    #Some code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    #Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need to annotate the methods you want to override.

Comment: Correct no NEED to, but in stack overflow we always promote good practices. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/94411/1492034 for more information why you shoud

Comment: It might be a good practice, but this does not answer or solve the issue.